# root and child domain controllers same subnet

Tags: active-directory

We are planning the following AD topology:

- ourcompany.com

  - east.ourcompany.com
  - west.ourcompany.com

The main root domain controllers and east.ourcompany.com domain controllers will exist in the same head office datacentre location:

dc1.ourcompany.com
dc2.ourcompany.com
dc1.east.ourcompany.com
dc2.east.ourcompany.com

west.ourcompany.com will be on a different subnet (and country) all together.

Do the head office domain controllers (the root and child domain) also need to be on a seperate subnet? I assume they do, unless we provide some kind of unique netbios names (and if so any recommendations for naming the above)?

Comment: I see your issue when naming the DC's the same. Couldn't you just name them differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a technical answer, but I personally always prefix server names with some form of site code. It can, admittedly, make the FQDN a little unweildy especially if the domain name is similar to the prefix, but perhaps something like this:

> Head Office = HO-DC01 & HO-DC02
>
> West Coast = WC-DC01 & W-DC02
>
> East Coast = EC-DC01 & E-DC02

So, you end up with HO-DC01.ourcompany.com, along with EC-DC01.east.ourcompany.com and WC-DC01.west.ourcompany.com

With the added benefit that everything still makes perfect logical sense (And works!) even when not referencing using a FQDN.

Comment: this is nice, DCHO001, DCWC001, DCEC001. Thanks for pointing me in a direction i can work with,

Answer (score 1):

they can coexist on the same network segment

Comment: Even with the same name? That's got to get you in some kind of trouble, even if the netbios name is not used as frequent as in NT?

Comment: you're right - name should be unique.